# VSCode no longer shows error in folded code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Previous version os VS Code would show squiggly lines if indicating a type error even in folded code blocks. This feature was very useful for quickly noticing problem areas in large code files even before compilation. For some reason, this feature is no longer available in the latest version. Did they just take it out, or is it enabled with a settings flag?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. What language are you working in? I recommend you [file a new issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) against VS Code so we can investigate

Comment: I am working with TypeScript.

Comment: VSCode issue has been opened at: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39787